# How to switch to BIOS boot from Mac EFI to make TTY work?

Tags: boot, nvidia, graphics, bootloader, macbook

I just want TTY:s and lock screen to work.
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers/+bug/958891/comments/3

The computer is Macbook and has such a problem with nvidia-340 driver.

https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1063182/linux/nvidia-drivers-don-t-include-access-to-tty-terminal-/post/5385376/#5385376

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/910409/change-from-uefi-to-legacy

Comment: I’ve just read your bug comments thoroughly and experienced that _you_ found [a way to solve your problem](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/light-locker/+bug/1811402/comments/3), didn’t you? Switching “back” to “BIOS” could _work around_ by setting the GPU differently in the early boot phase but Intel Macs _never had_ actual BIOS, they’ve used EFI right from Apple’s switch to Intel and provided some BIOS emulation for Windows XP, see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boot_Camp_(software)#Startup_Disk). I am voting to close this question as a bug report (and an X-Y problem).

Comment: @Melebius Moving to _nouveau_ driver has the side effect of losing ability to playback video properly by the hardware. On the other hand, support for the _nvidia_ driver will be over [soon](https://askubuntu.com/q/1146245/21005), so I guess it will be the only option then. If you can not switch back to BIOS by Macbook, then I wonder what the author of the comment did. Could settings be altered accordingly even when using _nvidia_ driver?

Comment: _“Moving to nouveau driver has the side effect of losing ability to playback video properly by the hardware.”_ You should [edit] your question to add this important information, see [ask]. _“On the other hand, support for the nvidia driver will be over soon”_ One more reason to file a bug report (to nouveau) instead of asking a question on AU! _“If you can not switch back to BIOS by Macbook, then I wonder what the author of the comment did.”_ You should ask him, Launchpad provides his e-mail address when you click on his name. I guess it would require reinstalling Ubuntu.

Comment: @Melebius I just asked if there was an easy fix, as this is regression, IIRC. Reserve engineering is not easy, apparently. Bug commenter may answer also in the bug comments or in here as he/she has been informed in the comments. If I want to ask about _nouveau_, I will make another thread.

Comment: AFAIK Ubuntu is installed in the same mode as the installer is run. When booting your installer media, you can [choose between “Windows” (legacy BIOS) and “EFI boot”](http://i.stack.imgur.com/kI5w8.jpg). However, I can only boot the EFI option of Xubuntu 18.04 on my MacBook Air 6,2. Selecting “Windows” results in a `Boot error`.